# Angular - Cannot populate mat-chip-list with collection and *ngFor - Updated: Set value of mat-select multiple is problem?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

I am having a problem populating a `mat-chip-list`. In my angular component which is contained within a modal window I pass data using `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`. This looks like so:

```
{
  name: 'string',
  email: 'string',
  tags: {
    company: [{displayName: 'string', id: ''}, ...] // can contain many or no items
  }
}
```

I pass this through to the component and assign the companies property to a `FormControl` when I create the `FormGroup` for the component (see code below). I then use a method to return the `FormControl` value so I can loop through the content to produce a `mat-chip-list`, here is my template code:

```
<mat-select formControlName="companies" multiple class="edit-user__form__chip-select">
  <mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-chip-list>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let company of outputChips('companies')"
                [removable]="true"
                (removed)="onChipRemove('companies', company)">
        {{ company.displayName }}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companyList" [value]="company">{{company.displayName}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

here is my code file (i have only included the relevant parts):

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditAccountComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data,
              private apiService: ApiService,
              private emailUniqueValidator: EmailUniqueValidator) {
    this.user = data;
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editAccountForm = this.createEditUserForm();
    // this returns a collection [{}, {}] where the objects have the same structure / signature
    // as the items contained with in the this.user.tags.company collection
    this.loadCompanies(); 
  }

createEditUserForm(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.user.name, [Validators.required, Validators.max(50)]),
      email: new FormControl(
        this.user.emailAddress,
        [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$')],
        this.emailUniqueValidator.validate.bind(this)
      ),
      companies: new FormControl(this.user.tags.company),
      roles: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

outputChips(control): any {
    return this.editAccountForm.controls[control].value;
  }

loadCompanies(): void {
    this.apiService.getTags('company', '').subscribe(tags => this.companyList = tags.slice(0, 20));
  }
```

Now my problem is that the `mat-chip-list` isn't being populated, however if I use the same code (`*ngFor`) with a `<div>` it will output the correct data. I am sure it maybe because I am using a `FormControl` to define the companies property/control of the `FormGroup`. So I changed this to a `FormArray` and formatted the this.user.tags.company to a FormArray like so...

```
createEditUserForm(): FormGroup {
    let formComps: FormArray;

    if (this.user.tags && this.user.tags.company) {
      formComps = new FormArray([...this.user.tags.company.map(item => new FormControl(item))]);
    }

    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.user.name, [Validators.required, Validators.max(50)]),
      email: new FormControl(
        this.user.emailAddress,
        [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$')],
        this.emailUniqueValidator.validate.bind(this)
      ),
      companies: new FormArray(formComps),
      roles: new FormArray([])
    });
  }
```

However this produces an error **"EditAccountComponent.html:38 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined"** so when I use FormArray I can't bind to the template. I really am having trouble trying to determine what I should do to make this work. I am currently looking through Stackoverflow for answers but if anyone can explain where I am going wrong and what I should do to fix my problem I would be most appreciative. If I have worded this question badly please comment and I shall rewrite and clarify.

** Update **

I'm starting to think that the problem isn't the mat-chip-list but the fact that the `companies: new FormControl(this.user.tags.company)`may not be correctly initialised, for example could this be a problem with setting the value or a mat-select with multiple values using a `formControlName` and not `ngModal`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over form array within your HTML you first need to specify **formArrayName** and then iterate over all of the controls. In your case, it should look more or less like that.

```
<mat-select formArrayName="companies" multiple class="edit-user__form__chip-select">
  <mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-chip-list>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let company of companies.controls"
                [removable]="true"
                (removed)="onChipRemove('companies', company)">
        {{ company.displayName }}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companyList" [value]="company">{{company.displayName}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

But I am not sure if your error doesn't point some other problem.

Comment: That doesn't really work, my code does work if I take the `mat-chip-list` outside the `mat-select-trigger` however I need it to work inside the `mat-select-trigger`

Comment: Could you provide some examples on the stackblitz? With real code, I could better help.

Comment: I have answered.